# Why is the scrollbar not hidden in my container element that has CSS parallax applied to it?

Tags: html, css, parallax

I used a tutorial to try parallax on a website and everything works fine, except I have a scrollbar within the parallax element. There is no margin on the body.

I was not able to find my answer by looking at other posts on here.

**Parallax CSS**

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    font-family: 'body-reg';
}

.row {
    width: 100%;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.B1 {
    height: calc(100vh - 20px);
    min-height: 300px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    -webkit-perspective: 10px;
    perspective: 10px;
}

.B1 .container--parallax {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    z-index: -1;
}

.B1 .container--parallax .background {
    transform: translateZ(-10px) scale(2);
}

.B1 .container--parallax .foreground {
    transform: translateZ(-5px) scale(1.5);
}

.B1 .container--parallax .background,
.B1 .container--parallax .foreground {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    -o-object-fit: cover;
    object-fit: cover;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <main>
        <section class="row B1">

            <div class="container--parallax">
                <img src="/assets/images/background.png" alt="Background" class="background"> 
                <img src="/assets/images/foreground.png" alt="Foreground" class="foreground">
            </div>

            <section class="row B2">

                <!-- add content -->

            </section>
        </section>

        <section class="row B3">

            <!-- more content -->

        </section>
    </main>
</body>
```

The  below body serves a purpose unrelated to this but has no styling applied to it.

**There should not be a scrollbar inside of .B1, so why is there?**

Answer (score 0):

Try using this!

```css
.B1 {
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
    scrollbar-width: none;
}
.B1::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none;
}
```

I can't figure out why yours has a scrollbar, but this should fix it. You likely have conflicting styling, but I can't find it.

Generally, this is the best-practice way to style/control scrollbars. Other methods may work, but this method prevents conflicting styling far more effectively.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because you have `overflow-y: auto;` inside your B1 class and another style is causing its content to exceed its size. Change your `B1` class to look like this if you want to prevent overflow on both the x and y axis.

```css
.B1 {
    height: calc(100vh - 20px);
    min-height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-perspective: 10px;
    perspective: 10px;
}
```